# Steam Account security

Tags: steam

I just recently started using steam again and was introduced to their new security system...

[image: Grr...]

...where I have to put a code (sent via email from steam) in everywhere i want to assess my account. Even if it's just on their website from my work.

What are the Pro's and Con's of this? It's really irritating to put in a code every time!

Steam asked me multiple times to authenticate my PC/Webbrowser. Is it just me or has this happend to other people as well?

---

**Extra Info**

Steam Guard will ask you to verify when reinstalling, and a second time when you replace your `steamapps` folder

Comment: Even though this is about a gaming website, it's not about a gaming topic.  It's about a web security topic.  Which is *off* topic for gaming.

Comment: soz. where should i ask this then?

Comment: @StrixVaria Web security? What the heck does this have to do with web security? It's a security feature of a gaming platform.

Comment: @Josefvz You could ask on http://security.stackexchange.com But I'm not sure if that would be on-topic.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Even if it is a security measure within a gaming platform, which I didn't realize at first (I thought it was only on steamcommunity.com), it's still *decidedly not related to gaming*.  It's a question about the pros and cons of a security feature.  Expertise in gaming adds *no insight* to the answer of this question.

Comment: The security feature also appears on the steam client

Comment: This is really just a question asking for the advantages of two-factor authentication. Phrased like that, it would fit on security.SE.

Comment: I disabled this feature since it would challenge me *every single time* I started Steam. Here's how: http://i.imgur.com/ovUUW.png

Comment: This is ridiculous, it is a question about a feature of a gaming platform that end users must make decisions about.  Decidedly on-topic for Gaming.SE.  Sure, it could go on other sites, but there is no rule that says sites must have zero overlap.

Comment: @NickT Meta topic: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2125/is-this-question-about-general-internet-security-on-topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pros for you
- If your account is stolen, the other users won't be able to repeatedly login with your account.

Cons for you
- You have to do a one-time validation

Pros for Steam
- It is harder for people to share accounts, since only one e-mail can be listed and they will always get the notifications.

Comment: You do have a choice.  It can be disabled, just look in your settings within Steam.

Comment: Not really a one-time validation as steam has asked me multiple times on the same machine

Comment: It is probably using a cookie, so if you delete the cookies from your machine you would need to validate again.

Comment: cookies are being used by browsers. THe steam Client itself asked me to validate multiple times

Comment: I think the bigger pro for Steam is that they don't have answer so many support calls about stolen accounts, saving them tons of support money.  This is the same reason Blizzard introduced two-factor authentication for their games.

Answer (score 7):

It's the usual security-convenience trade off to make it (slightly) harder to lose access to a Steam account. If your email password and your Steam passwords are the same, however, it won't do much.

Then again using the same password everywhere is a bad idea.